# R dplyr: Calculating row values by using previous row value and a function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a function in R that will allow me to determine the date at which a product will be out of stock. I would like this function to be able to account for scheduled incoming orders and show a "running total" of units in stock. Below is a reproducible idea of what I have been able to do thus far.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

runrate <- 25

onHand <- tibble(date = Sys.Date(), OnHand = 2000)

ord_tbl <- tibble(date = c(ymd("2020-04-09"), ymd("2020-04-12"), ymd("2020-04-17")), onOrder = c(200, 500, 100))



date_tbl <- tibble(date = seq.Date(from = Sys.Date(), to = Sys.Date() + 180, by = "day")) %>% 
                mutate(Month = month(date, label = TRUE))

joined_tbl <- date_tbl %>% 
    left_join(onHand) %>% 
    left_join(ord_tbl) 

joined_tbl <- joined_tbl %>% 
    mutate(OnHand = coalesce(joined_tbl$OnHand, 0),
           onOrder = coalesce(joined_tbl$onOrder, 0),
           id = row_number()) %>% 
    mutate(usage = id * runrate) %>% 
    select(id, everything()) 

start_inv_value <- joined_tbl %>% 
    filter(date == Sys.Date()) %>% 
    select(OnHand)

joined_tbl %>% 
    mutate(projected_On_Hand = start_inv_value$OnHand - (id * usage) + onOrder)
```

Ideally, I would like to take the starting inventory values on hand and then subtract the daily usage and add in units that are expected to be received; however, I am unable to bring down the previous days projected_on_hand value.

The anticipated results would look like this:

[image: Anticipated Results]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your expected output...for `id = 2` it seems like you want `1975 - 50 + 200 = 2125`. I guess it is not clear to me how you want to calculate `projected_On_Hand`. Your description and your anticipated results don't match uless I'm mistaken?

Comment: @paqmo Thank you reviewing my question and for taking time to respond. The OnHand quantity is what is currently available. By the end of the day I would have consumed 25 units of the 2000 which yields 1,975. The following day the OnHand Quantity should be the 1,975 units from the previous day, minus the 25 units used on 04-09-2020 which leaves 1950. I would then add the 200 units scheduled to arrive which would increase to projected_on_hand for that day to 2,150.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to include a cumulative sum of `onOrder` (use `cumsum`). In addition, you can just subtract usage for each row.

```
joined_tbl %>% 
  mutate(projected_On_Hand = start_inv_value$OnHand - usage + cumsum(onOrder))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 181 x 7
      id date       Month OnHand onOrder usage projected_On_Hand
   <int> <date>     <ord>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>             <dbl>
 1     1 2020-04-08 Apr     2000       0    25              1975
 2     2 2020-04-09 Apr        0     200    50              2150
 3     3 2020-04-10 Apr        0       0    75              2125
 4     4 2020-04-11 Apr        0       0   100              2100
 5     5 2020-04-12 Apr        0     500   125              2575
 6     6 2020-04-13 Apr        0       0   150              2550
 7     7 2020-04-14 Apr        0       0   175              2525
 8     8 2020-04-15 Apr        0       0   200              2500
 9     9 2020-04-16 Apr        0       0   225              2475
10    10 2020-04-17 Apr        0     100   250              2550
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you for your help!